# Problem with regenerating Id during entity edit via Thymeleaf

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am using SpringBoot 2.1.2 with Hibernate and Thymeleaf.

When user is editing entry (object Person) the new Id generates. Therefore instead of changing the state of the object, a new object is created. Other field keep the same.

Debug shows that edited model moves from Thymeleaf page to Controller (save() method) with the new Id generated.

```
    @Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GetMapping("/person-list")
    public String list(final Model model) {
        final Collection<Person> persons = personService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("persons", persons);
        return "person-list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/person-create")
    public String create() {
        personService.merge(new Person());
        return "redirect:/person-list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/person-remove")
    public String remove(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        personService.removeById(id);
        return "redirect:/person-list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/person-edit")
    public String edit(@RequestParam("id") String id, Map<String, Object> model) {
        final Person person = personService.findOneById(id);
        model.put("person", person);
        return "person-edit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/person-save")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
        personService.merge(person);
        return "redirect:/person-list";
    }

}
```

Source code of thymeleaf edit page below:

```
    <body>
        <div th:replace="fragments/header.html"></div>

        <form th:action="@{/person-save}" th:object="${person}" method="post">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200" nowrap="nowrap">ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Middle Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{middleName}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>E-mail</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{email}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <br/>
            <button type="submit">SAVE</button>
            <br/>
        </form>

        <div th:replace="fragments/footer.html"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

AbstractEntity as follows:

```
    @Getter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

}
```

Person entity presented below:

```
    @Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "app_persons")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.tasks"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Person.removeAll", query = "DELETE FROM Person p"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findOneByEmail", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.email = :personEmail"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findOne",
                query = "SELECT p FROM Person p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.tasks WHERE p.id = :personId")
})
public class Person extends AbstractEntity {

    @Nullable
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Nullable
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Nullable
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Nullable
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Nullable
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    public Person(@Nullable final String firstName, @Nullable final String lastName, @Nullable final String middleName,
                  @Nullable final String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return lastName + " " + firstName + " " + middleName;
    }

    public String getShort() {
        return lastName + " " + firstName;
    }

    public boolean isSelected(final String userId) {
        if (userId == null | userId.isEmpty()) return false;
        return getId().equals(userId);
    }

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try override `equals` and `hashcode` and check .

Comment: Do debug this, please check the following:
Does the `id` end up in the form; Does it get transmitted back to the server; 
Does the `id` actually gets set on the instance?

Comment: @manfromnowhere unfortunately, nothing changed.

Comment: @Jens Schauder I debugged, to edit method object transfers correctly, but after thymeleaf id regenerated